# What is the life of @Stateless EJB injected into JSF @SessionScoped?

Tags: jsf, ejb-3.0, stateless, session-scope

I'm converting some code to take advantage of EJB 3 and I've come up with a scenario where I have a @Stateless EJB being injected into JSF Managed bean that is annotated with @SessionScoped.

I was wondering how this effected the life of the EJB? Does it remain stateless and get destroyed after each call to one of its methods or does the same bean exist for the duration of the session?

Comment: Are you wondering what would happen or have tried it at least and got an error?

Comment: I don't have an error but the problem is unless I understand it, it might cause one down the line. Im trying to determine if the reference to the EJB is maintained for the life of the session or whether im getting a new reference every time the ejb is accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stateless EJB session beans are pooled by the server, there is no direct relationship with their lifecycle and the lifecycle of other session scoped beans. 
The webserver creates and destroys such beans when it needs to.
From the EJB spec:

> The container can perform the instance creation at any time—there is no direct relationship to a client’s invocation of a business method or the create method.

For more information see the [specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/ejb-3.1-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/ejb-3_1-fr-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1369146539_3e87457b19afb9d6e0b0e2e85e539f58) (around page 99).